# Adboe AGAL confused about the registers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, stage3d, agal

i hava a little confused about the registers.

in this article,  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/what-is-agal.html

there have two line AGAL code

```
m44 op, va0, vc0
mov v0, va1
```

the first line put the calculate result in op register,but the second line did not operate 
the op register,

so what's the meaning to do the first line?

also i found an demo:

```
//compile vertex shader
var vertexShader:Array =
    [
    "dp4 op.x, va0, vc0", //4x4 matrix transform from 0 to output clipspace
    "dp4 op.y, va0, vc1",
    "dp4 op.z, va0, vc2",
    "dp4 op.w, va0, vc3",
    "mov v0, va1.xyzw"    //copy texcoord from 1 to fragment program
    ];
var vertexAssembler:AGALMiniAssembler = new AGALMiniAssembler();
vertexAssembler.assemble(flash.display3D.Context3DProgramType.VERTEX, vertexShader.join("\n"));

//compile fragment shader
var fragmentShader:Array =
    [
    "mov ft0, v0\n",
    "tex ft1, ft0, fs1 <2d,clamp,linear>\n", //sample texture 1     
    "mov oc, ft1\n"
    ];
```

in vertexShader, top three line also put the reslut in op, but the fourth line alos not used it .

so what is that means?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First line simply multiplies current vertex position and Model-View-Projection matrix and writes the result to output register.

The second line uses varying register to pass some data to pixel shader. Since those two lines is all code I can see, all I can say is that va1 probably contains texture UV coords.

Comment: yes,so there is no connection between first line and second? can i interpreted as finally the GPU will operate the data in op and oc registers? in second demo,top 3 line in vertexShader already done the calculate,and put the result in op,the fourth line is use to put the data in v0,which will use in fragmentShader,and then in fragmentShader all data will store in oc. after that GPU can start operate the data in op and oc? do i correctly? thanks

Comment: No connection, both lines do different things.
Both pixel and vertex shaders execute on the GPU in such order:
vertex shaders > vertex clipping (done internally by GPU) > pixel shaders. Therefore GPU is operating everything from the point the first vertex shader is run.